# I was wondering if this sentence was correct

Tags: grammar

Yesterday as I was watching *Friends*, I came across a sentence that sounded weird.

The sentence was:

> He pretend, he don't hear me.

I think that the actress had made a mistake.Am I right?

Answer (score 3):

It may simply be that the script writer wants to signify the character is illiterate and poorly educated.

This storytelling device is often employed in novels, plays and films.

An example from *Pickwick Papers*, a novel by Charles Dickens, is the character Sam Weller, a cockney servant. The following exchange between the literate Mr Pickwick, who speaks in a standard way, and the more vernacular (and, by implication, less educated) Sam illustrates the technique:

> [Cliffsnotes](https://www.cliffsnotes.com/literature/p/the-pickwick-papers/summary-and-analysis/chapters-1112/chapters-1112-6)
>
> '*We want to know, in the first place*,' said Mr. Pickwick, '*whether you have any reason to be discontented with your present situation*.'
>
> '*Afore I answers that 'ere question, gen'l'm'n,*' replied Mr. Weller, '*I should like to know, in the first place, whether you're a-goin' to purwide me with a better?*'

Comment: Let me add that the character who speaks the line may be attributing the illiteracy to the person addressed.

Answer (score 0):

People use all sorts of strange constructions in direct speech that usually wouldn't work in written english. The question ought to be whether she is understood in the company she is. I read it as saying:

> He pretend[s]

To listen to me

> But he don't hear me

But he doesn't actually listen.

This is quite a common complaint that many people make. I think the sentence is understandable. Why the script-writer wanted to have the actress say this in this way at that point in the script is impossible to tell from the very short extract.

It might mean, for example, that the character is illiterate or poorly educated or it might mean that they are a highly educated immigrant from, say Belize, with a doctorate in Archaeology and the script-writer wanted to point and bring out this contrast. It could also be that the character is imitating a poorly educated person to make fun of the poor or even imitating a recent immigrant because he's a racist.

Without more context it's not possible to say.